# CFHTTP ERROR : Connection Failure. Status code unavailable

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml, cfc, coldfusion-2021

I am using coldfsuion 2021 and getting error while using **cfhttp **with Content-Type as '**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**'. Here I am attaching my code snippet and its result.
Please help me to solve this issue.

[image: Code Snippet]

[image: Result]

I have tried by creating API with lambda and called that API from ColdFusion page. But it again throwing same error. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: It looks like the target domain shopbunzlusa.com is not configured correctly. The domain owner will need to fix that otherwise pretty much any site visitor will see an error in their browser when visiting that site. The good news is when that is fixed coldfusion will also be able to connect. If things work in Azure like in AWS you will need to get an SSL cert for your domain and install it in Azure. But that is another question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

CFHTTP is having trouble verifying the certificate of the domain you are trying to access. You either need to add some additional certificates to your java cacerts file or you need to update the domain to serve its certificates a different way.